# What's the best way to communicate with a server, service-worker, global scope or it doesn't matter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, manifest

I am developing a *Chrome Extension* using *Manifest V3*, and I need to transcribe speech to a *Google Document*. I am currently using a *service-worker.js* to authenticate to Google using chrome.identity.getAuthToken, and I am communicating with my *main.js* via a port using `port.postMessage()`. However, I am experiencing performance and complexity issues with this approach.  How should I continue doing the communication, with the current sw, to create another js file or it doesn't matter?

Comment: What is `main.js` is it part of a popup, a content script ?

Comment: Yeah is a content script with the main logic

Comment: As far as I know, in MV3, you can only make API requests (AJAX) calls from the background service worker. Also, port connections work a bit different in MV3. I think you should keep the current approach but you may need to change it to `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(..)` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(..)` instead of a port connection. I think port connection can be disconnected unexpectedly where as, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(..)`, will start the service worker.